# Check if global searchable has been enabled by user

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I'm developing an Android app which provides a [search interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) to be used both locally and globally.

In order for the custom interface to appear in the system's Quick Search Box, the user has to explicitly enable it in the *Search settings*, which can be programmatically launched through the useful `android.app.SearchManager.INTENT_ACTION_GLOBAL_SEARCH` intent.

The question is: **how can I check programmatically if my searchable interface has been enabled by the user?**

The only thing getting me "almost there" is the [`SearchManager` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html), which provides (among others):

- [`getSearchablesInGlobalSearch` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#getSearchablesInGlobalSearch%28%29):
  returns a list containing searchable information for all searchable activities that have the `android:includeInGlobalSearch` attribute set in their searchable meta-data, *but no information whether the user has enabled them or not*.
- [`INTENT_ACTION_SEARCH_SETTINGS_CHANGED` intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#INTENT_ACTION_SEARCH_SETTINGS_CHANGED):
  action broadcasted to inform that the search settings have changed in some way; either searchables have been enabled or disabled, or a different web search provider has been chosen, *but again, no information on the actual changes*.

Extensive Googling on the matter fails, which could mean that either:

- I'm missing something exceptionally obvious (possible)
- it has never been attempted before (unlikely)
- it's simply impossible

Can somebody shed some light on this?

Comment: You got the desired results or not..

Comment: @Bhr eventually the project got dropped and I stopped investigating the matter... It you find a solution please post it here :)

Comment: I also left the thing aside..

Comment: @Takhion wich target SDK did you have in this project? I suspect that the big changes that the Search app had lately have something to do